# Design patterns for Android development

Tags: android

Going through job openings, I sometimes see the phrase "design patterns" listed as a requirement. The phrase "design pattern" is rather too generalized. When I think of design patterns, I often think of something like MVC (Model View Controller) but MVC doesn't really fit in well with Android, whereas it does fit in well with web applications.

If someone in a job interview asks me what design patterns do I know of for Android, I would be stumped. Can you indicate any major design patterns that Android developers might use so that I can get familiar with them? Thanks a million!

Comment: According to me design pattern is nothing special, It is just like the designing for android app. see here https://www.google.com/search?noj=1&biw=1787&bih=817&q=design+pattern+in+android&oq=design+pattern+in+android&gs_l=serp.3..0l2j0i22i30l7j0i22i10i30.2537661.2544240.0.2544770.25.24.0.1.1.0.424.4266.2-12j2j2.16.0....0...1c.1.46.serp..8.17.4262.1HZHAJJqN48

Comment: Most of the people who are posting job openings for Android are either startups or do not have adequate knowledge about the kind of Software Devlopment frameworks involved (This is true atleast in India). Some people look for Enterprise grade application experience and some others just make it more confusing by including the phrases like above. If I were the owner I would select a candidate purely based on experience and what a candidate has done so far, how well it fits to my problem specification.

Comment: +1 for your question..as till i am confuse in same.Can you please check http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/ .. it will give little idea.

Answer (score -3):

There are couple of design patterns being used by developer weather they are aware of it or not, below is the list of the most used

1. Observer pattern
2. Singeton Pattern
3. Factory Pattern
4. State Pattern
5. Filter Pattern
6. Iterator Pattern
7. Template Pattern
8. Adapter Pattern

Comment: These are generally used everywhere. This is Java specific that too on the code part. Not Design part.

Comment: Editing the question on the basis of an answer? Okay mate I am writing an answer, please type in your question accordingly :D